# Output the results of an Oracle cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, toad

I'm trying to output the results of an oracle cursor.  I was attempting to do this assuming the cursor had generic column names.  I wanto to output the results of the cursor to any output or watch this for debugging purposes.  I'm using toad but have not found a simple way to debug the output results.

```
DECLARE 
  MYRESULTS MYSCHMA.MYPKG.MYCURSOR;

BEGIN 
  MYRESULTS := NULL;

  MYSCHEMA.MYPKG.MYSPROC ( MYRESULTS );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('my results = '''||MYRESULTS.COLUMN1||'''' );
  COMMIT; 

END;
```

Comment: Are you asking how to construct dynamically inspect the cursor to determine the metadata (the names of the columns, data types, etc.) in order to output them using `dbms_output`?  Assuming that you have an arbitrary weakly typed ref cursor?  That's not going to be simple.  You've tagged this for both 10g and 11g-- do you need the code to be compatible with a 10.1 or 10.2 database?  Or can you use a solution that would only work with 11g (maybe 11.2)?  Can you resort to a Java stored procedure?  Are you restricted to PL/SQL solutions, or could you use SQL*Plus functions?

Comment: I'm trying to get the widest audience 10g and 11g but I'm only using 11g.  I'm restricted for now to PL/SQL due to time constraints.

Comment: I am trying to get the data results or the actual data and then filter it for debugging purposes.

Comment: @RetroCoder - if you want a broader audience then tag as [tag:oracle] rather than just release-specific tags which fewer people will see; in this case tagging as 11g as well will indicate that you need something that will work in that release so having that as well doesn't hurt.